# PHP: function with equality sign as parameter?

Tags: php, function

Can someone explain to me a variable declaration inside a definition of a function, like the one below. What's the purpose? The coding language I use is PHP.

```
function parse( $filename=FALSE ) {
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a default value for the function.  So if you call parse(), then $filename will be FALSE.  However, you could also call parse("/path/to/my/file") and then $filename will contain "/path/to/my/file"

Comment: thanks for the fast respond I will accept this answer as soon as possible(10 minutes).

Answer (score 2):

It means that when you call the `parse` function the parameter is *optional*; if you don't provide a value, then `FALSE` will be used instead.

You can see more details on the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) in the section "Default Argument Values".

Comment: @El yobo: Thanks for the qick respond!

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, it is the default value of that argument. If the $filename argument is not passed when calling the parse function, then the $filename variable will default to FALSE

```
function echostring($string = "no string passed") {
echo $string;
}

echostring() // will echo "no string passed"
echostring("hello world") // will echo "hello world"
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It is a [**function with default argument value**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

It means when calling the function `parse` passing argument to it is optional. If you don't pass any argument the variable `$filename` will take the default value of `FALSE` but if you do pass one, `$filename` will take the passed value.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a default value for the argument, so if you don't specify it in the call, the function still has a value to use for it.

In other words, if I write this function:

```
function doStuff($var1, $var2 = false) {
 // do stuff
}
```

Then calling the function like this:

```
 doStuff("thing1");
```

Is exactly the same as calling it like this:

```
 doStuff("thing1", false);
```

Also, a slight clarification on your question: The `=` operator isn't the "equality sign". It's actually the "assignment operator". To check equality in PHP, you use `==` (or `===` if you want to ensure the types are the same as well, not just the values).